# Index Link in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, c#-to-vb.net

How to add index link in pdf reports exported by crystal report ?
Example - my report has five pages, i have to give index on first page for those five pages, and that index has link, when i wll click on thet it will redirect to tht page ? Is there any functionality available in crystal report ?

Answer (score 0):

See list of 3rd-party Crystal Reports automation tools [here](http://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#desktopsched). 
At least one of these tools can automate the process of exporting a report to PDF and adding a linked Table of Contents.

Here's a description of [PDF Table of Contents functionality](https://milletsoftware.com/Visual_CUT_User_Manual/#Adding%20a%20Table%20of%20Content%20to%20a%20PDF%20File) in my Visual CUT software. And here's a [sample pdf file with a Table of Contents](http://www.milletsoftware.com/Download/VC_PDF_Table_of_Contents_Sample.pdf) generated using this approach.